# Community site having Navigation tab which has external site embedded but external site not redirecting to home page, how to fix this issue

Tags: experience-cloud, tab, iframe, lightning-connect, canvas-app

We are using Canvas app(Manage) for External site called (Seismic) and added that in our community site. In the Navigation bar we have Tab called Seismic, once we click on it will shows iframe and all UI for seismic. We want user to see home page when they click on the tab, currently they landing on client sub tab page instead of Home. How can I fix this? I checked Canvas App preview but it's not showing anything. It just loading the page and shows white screen.
App Manager I added url in Start URL box but still not much help.
Anybody please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After Investigation I noticed that it is 3rd party installed app and we don't have access to the url to update. It has been managing by Third party and had to reach out customer support to resolve this issue.

I hope this help somebody who is in a similar situation like me.